# How do I stop Filter retaining the order of source data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm wondering how to get a FILTER function in Google Sheets to order itself by the data it is matching to in its conditions.

[My example sheet is here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sT8UliVlFZCozfvRDoyaxF7KNw0jKj37l_rw2TMhHSk/edit#gid=2134765434)

In my example I have two sets of data in two sheets named "DS" and "SALESPIPELINE". DS contains a list of studios and dates, SALESPIPELINE also contains a list of studios and dates along with sales data such as leads, prospects, pre-quals, consults etc.

I want to bring the information from SALESPIPELINE to DS, but ordered correctly to match the studio and date columns in DS. I've tried a number of formulas, but currently the formula I am using is:

```
=FILTER(SALESPIPELINE!C2:I, MATCH(SALESPIPELINE!A2:A1000, A2:A, 0), MATCH(MONTH(SALESPIPELINE!B2:B), MONTH(B2:B), 0), MATCH(YEAR(SALESPIPELINE!B2:B), YEAR(B2:B), 0))
```

The filtered data is the correct data, but it retains the order of the data in SALESPIPELINE rather than matching to the columns in DS. I've tried wrapping the FILTER in the SORT function and sorting by SALESPIPELINE!A3:A14, but it doesn't seem to sort in order (this is also not a solution for me as the sort range needs to be dynamic as more data is added).

I've included a sheet that shows how the results would ideally come out. As you'll see, I'd like it to adopt the order of studios and dates in DS with the matching data from SALESPIPELINE.

Is FILTER the correct formula to be using, or would something like QUERY be more appropriate? (I did have a go at QUERY, but couldn't get it to work either)

Hope that makes sense - I would love some help figuring this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you can put in another tab)

```
=sort(filter({arrayformula(if(iserror(match(SALESPIPELINE!A:A,DS!A:A,0)&"~"&match(SALESPIPELINE!B:B,DS!B:B,0)),9^9,match(SALESPIPELINE!A:A,DS!A:A,0))),SALESPIPELINE!A:I},match(SALESPIPELINE!A:A,DS!A:A,0),match(SALESPIPELINE!B:B,DS!B:B,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand how your formula works, but it seems to be doing the trick both within the example and within my actual spreadsheet. I've just had to add a hidden column for the number it's sorting by, but that's no big deal at all.

Thank you so much! I will have to spend some time fiddling with this formula so I can learn how it works!

Comment: @RosieMuir, I kept your formula and added this column to sort as you correctly understood `arrayformula(if(iserror(match(SALESPIPELINE!A:A,DS!A:A,0)&"~"&match (SALESPIPELINE!B:B,DS!B:B,0)),9^9,match(SALESPIPELINE!A:A,DS!A:A,0)))` . In fact you can keep your formula as it is and build this additional column in first or last column. I was actually also amazed that it works without splitting the date by year and month and left it as is, but you can do it like you did before.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 
 FILTER({SALESPIPELINE!A2:A, SALESPIPELINE!C2:I}, 
 MATCH(SALESPIPELINE!A2:A1000, A3:A, 0), MATCH(MONTH(SALESPIPELINE!B2:B), MONTH(B3:B), 0), 
 MATCH(YEAR(SALESPIPELINE!B2:B), YEAR(B3:B), 0)), {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah this one does the trick too! As with the other solution, I'll need to fiddle this to figure out exactly how it works, but thank you very much for your help!